# Windows Firewall GPO not applying properly

Tags: windows, active-directory, firewall, group-policy

So I've got a small lab with 2 DCs, both running server 2019 core. I've created a GPO with some Firewall Rules and linked it at the top of the domain, applying to all devices, including both DCs.

DC1, which currently still holds all FSMO roles, has received the policy but the rules are not active

DC2, has received the policy and has all rules active.

I can't for the life of me figure out why one DC is properly applying the rules while the other isn't. I can navigate to the registry and see the firewall rules on both DCs, in an RSOP it shows that the computer is definitely receiving the policy and parsing it and I can even see the rules when searching for them in PowerShell, but ... then there's a difference when comparing both DCs:

DC1 (where rules are not applied):

```
EnforcementStatus Name Profile PrimaryStatus

----------------- ---- ------- -------------

ProfileInactive ComPlusNetworkAccess-DCOM-In Domain Inactive

{ProfileInactive, Enforced} RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-UDP Any OK

{ProfileInactive, Enforced} RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP Any OK

ProfileInactive RemoteEventLogSvc-RPCSS-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive RemoteEventLogSvc-NP-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive RemoteEventLogSvc-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive RVM-RPCSS-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive RVM-VDSLDR-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive RVM-VDS-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive ComPlusRemoteAdministration-DCOM-In Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive WMI-ASYNC-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive WMI-WINMGMT-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive WMI-RPCSS-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive RemoteTask-RPCSS-In-TCP Domain Inactive

ProfileInactive RemoteTask-In-TCP Domain Inactive
```

Whereas on DC2 they look like this:

```
EnforcementStatus Name Profile PrimaryStatus

----------------- ---- ------- -------------

Enforced ComPlusNetworkAccess-DCOM-In Domain OK

{ProfileInactive, Enforced} RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-UDP Any OK

{ProfileInactive, Enforced} RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP Any OK

Enforced RemoteEventLogSvc-RPCSS-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced RemoteEventLogSvc-NP-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced RemoteEventLogSvc-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced RVM-RPCSS-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced RVM-VDSLDR-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced RVM-VDS-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced ComPlusRemoteAdministration-DCOM-In Domain OK

Enforced WMI-ASYNC-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced WMI-WINMGMT-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced WMI-RPCSS-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced RemoteTask-RPCSS-In-TCP Domain OK

Enforced RemoteTask-In-TCP Domain OK
```

So in short, all rules applied via GPO to DC1 are in "Inactive" status and show enforcement status as "ProfileInactive" - which point to the Domain profile being disabled, but that's actually not the case at all - all firewall profiles are enabled on both DCs and of course there are some custom (domain profile) rules that get enabled by DCPromo anyway so that profile has to be up and working, but here from both DCs

DC1:

```
Name : Domain

Enabled : True

DefaultInboundAction : NotConfigured

DefaultOutboundAction : NotConfigured

AllowInboundRules : NotConfigured

AllowLocalFirewallRules : NotConfigured

AllowLocalIPsecRules : NotConfigured

AllowUserApps : NotConfigured

AllowUserPorts : NotConfigured

AllowUnicastResponseToMulticast : NotConfigured

NotifyOnListen : False

EnableStealthModeForIPsec : NotConfigured

LogFileName : %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log

LogMaxSizeKilobytes : 4096

LogAllowed : False

LogBlocked : False

LogIgnored : NotConfigured

DisabledInterfaceAliases : {NotConfigured}
```

DC2:

```
Name : Domain

Enabled : True

DefaultInboundAction : NotConfigured

DefaultOutboundAction : NotConfigured

AllowInboundRules : NotConfigured

AllowLocalFirewallRules : NotConfigured

AllowLocalIPsecRules : NotConfigured

AllowUserApps : NotConfigured

AllowUserPorts : NotConfigured

AllowUnicastResponseToMulticast : NotConfigured

NotifyOnListen : False

EnableStealthModeForIPsec : NotConfigured

LogFileName : %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log

LogMaxSizeKilobytes : 4096

LogAllowed : False

LogBlocked : False

LogIgnored : NotConfigured

DisabledInterfaceAliases : {NotConfigured}
```

Anyone got any clues of where the problem might lie?

Answer (score 1):

In the network settings on DC1, are you connected to the domain profile?
Settings -> Network & Internet -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change advanced sharing settings -> Ensure Domain is current profile.

Comment: You're on the right track, but I think you missed the part about it being a *server core* - i.e., no GUI so your instructions can't be performed. Still, the server does think it is on a public network, yes. And yet, you cannot manually change it to a domain network, that's something that machines decide on their own, whether they are on a domain network or not.

Comment: I did, sorry about that. Can you restart the network location awareness service while everything is connected?

Comment: NlaSvc can't be restarted that easily on domain joined machines ... I did disable the NIC and re-enabled it and that fixed it, but it will happen again on next restart... not a fix.

Comment: I saw this on another site: 
start regedit

navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc

Edit 'DependOnService

Add new line with "DNS"
Source: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/server-2019-network-profile-network-location-awareness-and/m-p/322432

Comment: I added an answer of my own detailing the problem and the solutions as I see it. Thank you for your answer and research, it has really helped me to find the cause of the problem and all potential solutions.

Comment: Hey Cogumel, glad to help.  This is my first time commenting on the site, so I am happy you figured it out. I was thinking the same thing for the delayed start on nla.  Good job on figuring that out!

Answer (score 0):

KB162 was correct in that DC1 thought it was in a public network location rather than domain.

As for the reason...

Well the service NlaSvc (Network Location Service) is responsible for determining the network location of a device. In order to do that, it relies (maybe among other things) on DNS.

This DC's NIC had 2 DNS entries as follows (in this order):

- 127.0.0.1
- DC2

The DNS service was starting after the NLA service causing the server to think that it was in a public location. Although DC2 also has 127.0.0.1 as the first DNS server, it doesn't suffer from these problems though, which means that a race condition is happening and that DC1 might not always be affected by this issue either.

A bit of research shows a few possible solutions:

1. Set NlaSvc to Automatic (Delayed Start)
2. Add a dependency of DNS to NlaSvc
3. Change the DNS server order to first go to the other DC and then itself.

First option does not necessarily solve it since it's a race condition and we don't know how long the DNS server takes to start up. It will most likely always fix it, but I don't believe we can guarantee with 100% certainty that it will never happen again.

Second option is a bit of a hack and I would argue unsupported and it may even be that Microsoft changes these values during an update, it's just impossible to know for sure.

As for the third option... while it solves it in a situation where at least one of the DCs is up, it will still present a problem when both DCs are down: the first one to be booted will look at the other DC for DNS, it doesn't reply, NlaSvc will set network location to public, DNS service starts, NlaSvc doesn't change it anymore. Second DC to start will be fine though.

I think that I will go with the first option as it arguably provides the best support and will monitor from there.

Thank you to KB162 for helping me get to this solution.